# Is there any in-memory MongoDb server for .net platform?

Tags: .net, mongodb

Trying to run integration tests on my application. Can't find any similar mongodb in-memory server as it is in node environment (mongodb-memory-server).

Comment: What do you mean? MongoDB runs also on Windows. Note, you have to download the Enterprise Edition. For developing the Enterprise Edition is also free.

Answer (score 1):

The "in-memory" part of https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server implies, I guess, the use of the ephemeralForTest storage engine. It doesn't mean an embedded server instance.

You can run the same MongoDB configuration in a standalone manner by inspecting the source of mongodb-memory-server and doing what it does using a language of your choice (including shell scripts).

Note that ephemeralForTest storage engine [doesn't support transactions](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38762) and is therefore of limited use on MongoDB 4.0 and newer servers.

You can have all features of MongoDB with in-memory storage if you use [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram), which works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I used Mongo2Go and it is working fine https://github.com/Mongo2Go